SwiftUI modify image frame
I have an image that I would like to always use the maximum available width. However the image should have a max height of 500 and should only utilize the height if it will fill it. Currently wide images dont fill the full height but the images frame is still 500 and hence why the text views are far away from the image. When the image is taller the width is not all used. How can I use the correct modifiers for this need?
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            KFImage(URL(string: "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg"))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .frame(maxHeight: 500)
                .clipped()
            Text("hello")
           
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}


//image: smaller width, larger height
//"https://media.macphun.com/img/uploads/customer/how-to/608/15542038745ca344e267fb80.28757312.jpg?q=85&w=1340"

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView()
}

Current result


You question is a bit vague to me
1️⃣ First Though: Same Width - Same Height
If I understand you correctly, You are looking for kind ofFill behavior like this:
 
You can use a placeholder view and use the image inside it's overlay like:
VStack {
    Text("hello")

    Color.clear //  use it as a placeholder view
        .overlay (
            KFImage(URL(string: "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg"))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill() //  Fill instead of Fit
        )
        .frame(maxHeight: 500) //  Apply modifications on the container
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
        .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
        .clipped()

    Text("hello")

}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)


2️⃣ Second Though: Same Width - Fit Content's Height
If you just need to fit the height of the image container to the image content like this:
 
You just need to add one more modifier:
KFImage(URL(string: "https://media.macphun.com/img/uploads/customer/how-to/608/15542038745ca344e267fb80.28757312.jpg?q=85&w=1340"))
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
    .frame(maxHeight: 500)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) //  Add this one here
    .clipped()


Thanks a lot!! The fixedSize modifier solved it. Your second approach was what I was looking for.

If I understand correctly, a wide image needs to be scaled to fit, but a tall image needs to be scaled to fill (so that all of the width is used).

In both cases, a maximum height of 500 should be enforced and the image should be clipped if the scaled height exceeds 500.
If the scaled image has a height of less than 500, it should only use the height it actually needs.

Try ViewThatFits, constraining on the  .horizontal axis only:
VStack {
    Text("hello")

    ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
        let theImage = KFImage(URL(string: "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg"))

        theImage
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(maxHeight: 500)

        theImage
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))

    Text("hello")
}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)

Here are your two test cases:


However, you have to look quite closely to notice that the tall test case has been cropped, because its proportions are very close to the frame it is being scaled to fill. So here are the results when test cases based on the system images "tortoise.fill", "lizard.fill", and "figure.stand" are used instead:




Thanks a lot, can you please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78447347/tab-view-does-not-animate-as-expected
