Tab View does not animate as expected
I have an Instagram stories clone and I’m running into an issue where once the user has gone through all the images for 1 set of stories and clicks to the next, the tab view does not do the box rotation animation. Instead, the next set of stories is displayed. The box rotation effect works just fine if I swipe between tabs. But it doesn't work by clicking to the next set of stories. The logic for this to actually switch the tab is in the function updateStory and inside the bottom else statement. Also if the time runs out on the last image then the next story is presented without the box animation. This is the same problem though so the solution should fix both bugs.
Also swiping to the next story if I am currently on the last story should cause the story view to close.
UPDATE. I solved the second issue where the story view closes if the last story is swiped out of bounds. I just need someone to help solve the animated tab rotation!
import SwiftUI

struct HomeX: View {
    @StateObject private var storyData = StoryViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 12){
                    ForEach($storyData.stories) { $bundle in
                        Circle().frame(width: 80).foregroundStyle(.blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                bundle.isSeen = true
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                                    storyData.currentStory = bundle.id
                                    storyData.showStory = true
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay {
            StoryViewX()
        }
        .environmentObject(storyData)
    }
}

struct StoryViewX: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var storyData: StoryViewModel
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = .zero
    @State var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @State var small: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var big: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        if storyData.showStory {
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                
                TabView(selection: $storyData.currentStory) {
                    ForEach(storyData.stories) { bundle in
                        StoryCardView(bundle: bundle)
                            .tag(bundle.id)
                            .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                            .rect { tabProgress(tabID: bundle.id, rect: $0, size: size) }
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.black.opacity(opacity))
            .transition(.offset(y: screenSize.height + 50))
            .environmentObject(storyData)
            .disabled(storyData.isAnimating)
        }
    }
    var screenSize: CGSize {
        if let screen = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow?.screen {
            return screen.bounds.size
        }
        return .zero
    }
    func tabProgress(tabID: String, rect: CGRect, size: CGSize) {
        if let index = storyData.stories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == tabID }), let last = storyData.stories.last, tabID == storyData.currentStory && last.id == tabID {
            
            let offsetX = rect.minX - (size.width * CGFloat(index))
            progress = -offsetX / size.width
            
            let temp: CGFloat = progress - CGFloat(index)
            
            
            
            if temp >= 0.05 {
                self.opacity = 1.0 - min(1.0, (temp / 1.5))
                
                self.big = temp
                if small > (big + 0.05) {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        storyData.showStory = false
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
                    self.small = temp
                }
                
            } else {
                self.opacity = 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}

import Kingfisher

struct StoryCardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var storyData: StoryViewModel
    var bundle: StoryBundle
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var timerProgress: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            ZStack {
                let activeIndex = min(Int(timerProgress), bundle.stories.count - 1)
                if bundle.stories.indices.contains(activeIndex) {
                    KFImage(URL(string: bundle.stories[activeIndex].imageURL))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                        .transition(.identity)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .overlay {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.clear)
                        .contentShape(.rect)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if (timerProgress - 1) < 0 {
                                updateStory(forward: false)
                            } else {
                                timerProgress = CGFloat(Int(timerProgress - 1))
                            }
                        }
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.clear)
                        .contentShape(.rect)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if (timerProgress + 1) > CGFloat(bundle.stories.count) {
                                updateStory()
                            } else {
                                timerProgress = CGFloat(Int(timerProgress + 1))
                            }
                        }
                }
                .padding(.top, 50)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(bundle.stories) { story in
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            let width = proxy.size.width
                            let index = CGFloat(bundle.stories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == story.id }) ?? 0)
                            let progress = timerProgress - index
                            let perfectProgress = min(max(progress, 0), 1)
                            
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.5))
                                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Capsule()
                                        .fill(.white)
                                        .frame(width: width * perfectProgress)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 1.4)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .rotation3DEffect(
                angle(proxy),
                axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0),
                anchor: proxy.frame(in: .global).minX > 0 ? .leading : .trailing,
                perspective: 2.5
            )
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                let degree = angle(proxy).degrees
                if timerProgress < CGFloat(bundle.stories.count) {
                    if degree == .zero {
                        timerProgress += 0.03
                    }
                } else if degree == .zero && storyData.showStory {
                    updateStory()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            timerProgress = 0
            timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
        }
    }
 
    func updateStory(forward: Bool = true) {
        Task {
            let index = min(Int(timerProgress), bundle.stories.count - 1)
            let story = bundle.stories[index]
            
            if !forward {
                if let first = storyData.stories.first, first.id != bundle.id {
                    let bundleIndex = self.index(bundle)
                    storyData.isAnimating = true
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        storyData.currentStory = storyData.stories[bundleIndex - 1].id
                    }
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
                    storyData.isAnimating = false
                } else {
                    timerProgress = 0
                }
            } else if let last = bundle.stories.last, last.id == story.id {
                if let lastBundle = storyData.stories.last, lastBundle.id == bundle.id {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        storyData.showStory = false
                    }
                } else {
          
        // HERE -- WHY DOES THIS NOT ROTATE TO THE NEXT TAB??
        // THE currentStory var is what is binded to the tabview     
 
                    let bundleIndex = self.index(bundle)
                    storyData.isAnimating = true
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        storyData.currentStory = storyData.stories[bundleIndex + 1].id
                        storyData.stories[bundleIndex + 1].isSeen = true
                    }
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
                    storyData.isAnimating = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func angle(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Angle {
        let progress = proxy.frame(in: .global).minX / proxy.size.width
        
        let rotationAngle: CGFloat = 45
        let degrees = rotationAngle * progress
        
        return Angle(degrees: Double(degrees))
    }
    func index(_ bundle: StoryBundle) -> Int {
        return storyData.stories.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == bundle.id }) ?? 0
    }
}






//NOT IMPORTANT

class StoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stories : [StoryBundle] = [
        StoryBundle(profileName: "iJustine", profileImage: "Pic1", stories: [
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
        ]),
        
        StoryBundle(profileName: "Jenna Ezarik", profileImage: "Pic2", stories: [
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
        ]),
        
        StoryBundle(profileName: "iJustine", profileImage: "Pic1", stories: [
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
        ]),
        StoryBundle(profileName: "Jenna Ezarik", profileImage: "Pic2", stories: [
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://pixlr.com/images/index/ai-image-generator-three.webp"),
            StoryX(imageURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_1280.jpg"),
        ]),
    ]
    
    @Published var showStory: Bool = false
    @Published var currentStory: String = ""
    @Published var isAnimating: Bool = false
}

struct StoryBundle: Identifiable,Hashable{
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var profileName: String
    var profileImage: String
    var isSeen: Bool = false
    var stories: [StoryX]
    
    mutating func updateStatus(_ seen: Bool) {
        isSeen = seen
    }
}

struct StoryX: Identifiable,Hashable{
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var imageURL: String
}
#Preview(body: {
    HomeX()
})
struct RectKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func rect(completion: @escaping (CGRect) -> ()) -> some View {
        self
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader {
                    let rect = $0.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal))
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: RectKey.self, value: rect)
                        .onPreferenceChange(RectKey.self, perform: completion)
                }
            }
    }
}


What is .rect modifier? Please provide a working sample

@MojtabaHosseini thanks for pointing that out! I have added the .rect modifier. Im sorry for not originally including it. I would appreciate help in solving this.

The issue:
This happens because you are invalidating the view in onAppear which prevents the animation.
The patch:
With your code style, the simplest way to patch (and verify) this issue it to add a little bit of delay (same as the animation duration) to the timer inside the onAppear. You can also move it to the task modifier like:
.onAppear {
    timerProgress = 0
    // timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect() //  This is causing the issue
}
.task {
    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
    timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
}

The Deeper Roadmap
You should try minimizing the usage of high frequent timer. I'm not going to rewrite the code now (because you will be lost), but I try to give you a roadmap on refactor:

Try to keep the activeIndex around in a dedicated State instead of calculating it from the progress.
Use the activeIndex to handle the current visible story by a simple expression like activeIndex += 1 for the next and activeIndex -= 1 for the previous.
Observe on the changes of the ActiveIndex to see if you should Go Next Person or dismiss the view or etc.
Use a simple animation to fill the Capsules with the desired duration.

In conclusion, stay use a stable index to control the animation logic and you will be good to go.
Here is a simple demo to mimic this roadmap in a standalone project:
struct Question78447347: View {
    let storiesCount = 3
    @State private var activeIndex = -1 //  Keep The activeIndex around

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<storiesCount, id: \.self) { index in
                    Capsule()
                        .mask(alignment: .leading) {
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(maxWidth: index <= activeIndex ? .infinity : 0)
                                .animation(
                                    .linear(duration: 1), //  Control the animation
                                    value: activeIndex //  Animate the changes
                                )

                                .id(index < activeIndex ? UUID().uuidString : "\(index)")
                                .transition(.identity)
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 10)

            Spacer()

            Button("Next") { activeIndex += 1 } //  Control the logic
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .onChange(of: activeIndex) { _ in //  Observe the changes of the index and decide the destination 
            if activeIndex >= storiesCount {
                print("Go to the next person or dismiss or something")
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks a lot for finding the issue. This does fix the general issue but there's a lot of corner cases where the animation still doesn't work. For example switching stories right when the view appears results in no animation. Any ideas for a fix to encapsulate all edge cases?

I have added a simple road map to refactor your code. feel free to ask any further questions about it

Thanks, I accepted your answer. Im a beginner with swift UI and I wouldn't really know how to implement your roadmap. Anyway you could show me what to do? I didn't write the original code, it was pulled from a repo.

I have added a simple demo of the roadmap but applying it on the original code requires you to fully understand both the demo and the original code and glue them together

Thanks a lot for your help. I spent a few hours and I wasn't really able to refactor your example with my long code. I posted a new question, if you have the time I'd appreciate the help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78470008/tab-view-does-not-animate-as-immediately
